# When we enable any service using systemctl, in which runlevel would that service run?

Tags: services, systemd

As far as I know when we boot Linux system the services mentioned in runlevels (`rcX.d`) would be started.

If we enable any service to start during boot-up using `systemctl` command then will that service will be added to that default runlevel?

Answer (score 7):

Actually no, it does not but you can run:

```
systemctl show -p WantedBy service-name
```

to find that in which target it would be run, for example:

```
systemctl show -p WantedBy tlp.service 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which indicates that if I enable `tlp` it would be started when I get into `multi-user.target`.

Also worth to mention that run-levels are deprecated and systemd uses target instead:

```
┌─────────┬───────────────────┐
│Runlevel │ Target            │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│0        │ poweroff.target   │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│1        │ rescue.target     │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│2, 3, 4  │ multi-user.target │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│5        │ graphical.target  │
├─────────┼───────────────────┤
│6        │ reboot.target     │
└─────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First of all I wanna say sorry that I didn't get exactly as I'm new to Linux. My doubts are: 1. where are target files stored in ubuntu?  2. why is run level needed when there's a concept of targets? 3. when we enable any service will that service will be added in rcx.d files also? 4. when system boots from where it will fetch the list of services to  start?   Thank you.

Comment: @ShreyKanna Runlevels are an outdated concept from the days when sysv-init was used to boot up the system. Systemd introduced the concept of targets and maintains a mapping of the old runlevels for compatibillity. In cases where there's only a legacy service definition available, it will automatically try to create a unit file from it, and link it to the appropriate target.wants directory. Systemd never uses the rcx.d directories.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I know when we boot Linux system the services mentioned in runlevels (rcX.d) would be started.

## This is not true anymore.

The `systemd` init system does not natively use a concept of run-levels. Instead, it introduces a concept of "targets" which group other units by using the mechanism of dependencies.

What was a "default runlevel" becomes the `default.target` unit which, when activated (started), can "pull in" (activate) other units via requirement dependencies.

(`systemd` *does* provide some compatibility layer for the run-level concept, in form of giving some targets aliases with names like `runlevelX.target`, which are then used by the tools like `telinit`, but that's about it.
In systemd, a service or any other unit is not required to belong to any of these pseudo-runlevels.)

## To enable a service (usually) is to create an artificial dependency between two units.

So, when you enable a service (or any unit), systemd takes a look at that unit's `[Install]` section and performs actions specified therein. For example, let's take a look at `sshd.service` on my machine:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Daemon
Wants=sshdgenkeys.service
After=sshdgenkeys.service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshd -D
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# This service file runs an SSH daemon that forks for each incoming connection.
# If you prefer to spawn on-demand daemons, use sshd.socket and sshd@.service.
```

When you write `systemctl enable sshd.service`, systemd looks at this unit and adds a `Wants=` dependency from `multi-user.target` to `sshd.service` according to the `WantedBy=multi-user.target` directive.

(This dependency is physically stored as a symlink from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service`.)

## So, when you boot...

When you boot, `default.target` gets activated, along with anything else it pulls in via dependencies. This is called "the initial transaction", and that's it.

Your `default.target` is likely an alias to `graphical.target` (which `Wants=multi-user.target`) or to `multi-user.target` directly. Either way, `multi-user.target` gets activated and pulls in `sshd.service` via the above-mentioned dependency.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have some doubts please clarify it.1. where are target files stored in ubuntu? 2. why is run level needed when there's a concept of targets? 3. when we enable any service will that service will be added in rcx.d files also? 4. when system boots from where it will fetch the list of services to start? Thank you.

Comment: @ShreyKanna 1. Alongside other units, see `man systemd`. 2. It's not. 3. Not necessarily, because enablement is not restricted to WantedBy= from runlevel-mapped targets. 4. When system boots, it starts `default.target`. Everything else is started by dependency.

Comment: gr8 Q&A, @intelfx, on my system I see sshd.service linked to file in system dir`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 22 22:42 /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service -> /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service` . what does files in `system` folder mean, by which target will be used